# Setting and updating state in React JS with Dropdown component from Material UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have this piece of code that calls a web service and displays the names coming from that WS into a Dropdown component from Material UI,

What I want to do is to set the default value of the dropdown with the first element coming from the WS and also be able to select any of the options in dropdown, I read something about "**State**" but don't get it really good at a code level.

I'm new to React and learning by myself but some help would be nice.

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import DropDownMenu from 'material-ui/DropDownMenu';
    import MenuItem from 'material-ui/MenuItem';

    export default class WebserviceTest extends Component {

      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
        data: [],
       };
       this.renderOptions = this.renderOptions.bind(this);
     }

     componentDidMount() {
     const url = 'https://randomuser.me/api/?results=4';

     fetch(url)
       .then(Response => Response.json())
       .then(findResponse => {
         console.log(findResponse);
         this.setState({
           data: findResponse.results
         });
       });
    }
    //will set wahtever item the user selects in the dropdown
    handleChange(event, index, value) {this.setState({ value });}
    //we are creating the options to be displayed
    renderOptions() {
     return this.state.data.map((dt, i) => {
       return (
         <div key={i}>
           <MenuItem
             label="Select a description"
             value={dt.name.first}
             primaryText={dt.name.first} />
         </div>
       );
     });
    }

    render() {
     return (
       <div>
         <DropDownMenu value={this.state.name} onChange={this.handleChange}>
           {this.renderOptions()}
         </DropDownMenu>
       </div>
     );
   }
  }
```

Thanks in advance.

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set state of selected dropdown option. And set first value of data as selected value.

```
componentDidMount() {
 const url = 'https://randomuser.me/api/?results=4';

 fetch(url)
   .then(Response => Response.json())
   .then(findResponse => {
     console.log(findResponse);
     this.setState({
       data: findResponse.results,
       selected: findResponse.results[0].name.first // need to be sure it's exist
     });
   });
}
handleChange(event, index, value) {this.setState({ selected: value });}
.
.
.
render() {
 return (
   <div>
     <DropDownMenu value={this.state.selected} onChange={this.handleChange}>
       {this.renderOptions()}
     </DropDownMenu>
   </div>
 );
```

}

> UPDATED CODE

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import DropDownMenu from 'material-ui/DropDownMenu';
import MenuItem from 'material-ui/MenuItem';

export default class WebserviceTest extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      data: [],
      selected: '',
    };
    this.renderOptions = this.renderOptions.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const url = 'https://randomuser.me/api/?results=4';

    fetch(url)
      .then(Response => Response.json())
      .then(findResponse => {
        console.log(findResponse);
        console.log(findResponse.results[0].name.first);
        this.setState({
          data: findResponse.results,
          selected: findResponse.results[0].name.first // need to be sure it's exist
        });
      });
  }
  handleChange(value) {this.setState({ selected: value });}

  //we are creating the options to be displayed
  renderOptions() {
    return this.state.data.map((dt, i) => {
      return (
        <div key={i}>
          <MenuItem
            value={dt.name.first}
            primaryText={dt.name.first} />
        </div>
      );
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <DropDownMenu value={this.state.selected} onChange={this.handleChange}>
          {this.renderOptions()}
        </DropDownMenu>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for your time, I tried this solution but the dropdown still blank when render the page, about this "selected: findResponse.results[0].name.first" I'm pretty sure it exists because I'm printing the result in console from findResponse and I can see the 4 elements I'm calling from the WS.

Comment: Done, I update the question and add the updated code.  Thanks again

Comment: Oh i found a problem. You've changed MenuItem value to this.state.selected! this.state.selected means currently selected value. So MenuItem's value should be the variable you set originally(dt.name.first).

Comment: Sorry, just made the update...  but even with the setState.selected the behavior is the same, don't display the first name and If I try to select another option the dropdown never close..

Comment: Did you bind handleChange? And could you show me updated code?

Comment: I had this line "this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);" commented, I removed the comment and leave the code as I have it right now. but without the comment still working the same way

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159435/discussion-between-kennechu-and-godsenal).

Answer (score 1):

`this.setState` controls the variable `this.state` in a special way. Whenever you use `this.setState` it will run `render` again to check for changes accordingly. Your dynamic content that you want to be responsive should be placed in `this.state` and those should be shown in your `render` function.

There are many ways to go about solving your question, but the most important principle to use is to place what you currently want to render (or the id/index number) in `this.state` and use `this.setState` to change it as needed.

`value={this.state.name}` should be a single value from your data structure that you return from your `fetch`, assuming this is what is shown on the screen.

Also, you forgot to `bind` `this.handleChange` in your constructor.

Stating `props` in your constructor is perfectly fine to do. You only do that when you want to use something from `this.props` in your constructor.  You aren't, so it's perfectly safe to leave it as `constructor()` and `super()`